# Finding common characters java

Tags: java

I am having problem in my code and I cannot figure out why?
I am trying to compare strings to find common characters. I am missing the first character of first letter.

```
 package findEquals;

import java.io.*;

class charequals {

    public String name1, name2;
    int l1, l2, m;

    void getInputs() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            System.out
                    .println("Enter First Name(Enter \"1\" for \"AMITABH BACHCHAN\")\n");

            name1 = br.readLine();
            if (name1.equals("1"))
                name1 = "AMITABH BACHCHAN";
            System.out
                    .println("Enter Second Name(Enter \"1\" for \"RAJNIKANTH\")\n");

            name2 = br.readLine();
            if (name2.equals("1"))
                name2 = "RAJNIKANTH";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void findEquals() {
        getInputs();
        l1 = name1.length();
        l2 = name2.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (name1.charAt(i) == name1.charAt(j)) {
                    m = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (m == 0) {
                m = 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < l2; k++) {
                if (name2.charAt(k) == name1.charAt(i)) {
                    System.out.println(name1.charAt(i) + " ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        charequals a = new charequals();
        a.findEquals();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT(for default values): I T H N

It should be : A I T H N
Why am I missing the first letter?

Comment: Man but the reason why you miss the A is because m = 0, when your program says if (m == 0) { m=1; continue; } as m statar with 0 you always gonna miss the first letter no matter what word you write. Do you want me to post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
import java.io.*;

class charequals {

    public String name1, name2;
    int l1, l2, m;

    void getInputs() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            System.out
                    .println("Enter First Name(Enter \"1\" for \"AMITABH BACHCHAN\")\n");

            name1 = br.readLine();
            if (name1.equals("1"))
                name1 = "AMITABH BACHCHAN";
            System.out
                    .println("Enter Second Name(Enter \"1\" for \"RAJNIKANTH\")\n");

            name2 = br.readLine();
            if (name2.equals("1"))
                name2 = "RAJNIKANTH";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void findEquals() {
        getInputs();
        l1 = name1.length();
        l2 = name2.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++) {
                if ( name1.charAt(i) == name2.charAt(j) ) {
                    System.out.print(name2.charAt(j) + " " );
                    char[] chars = name2.toCharArray();
                    chars[j] = '&';
                    name2 = new String(chars);
                    break;
                }
           }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        charequals a = new charequals();
        a.findEquals();
    }
}
```

The changes are in findEquals(), i dind't understands very well your code but i guees this may help you to solve your problem. [This work on ideone](http://ideone.com/ByWi4e)